# Size of the node of a binary tree in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, size, binary-tree

I was asked to provide the `size` of this `Node` in a binary tree.

Here is a simple `Node` class.

```
class Node {
   Integer data;
   Node left, right;
}

Node integerNode = new Node(1000);
integerNode.left=someIntegerNode1;
integerNode.right=someIntegerNode2;
```

Given `Node` has some `data` and both `left` and `right` references are not `null`. How would you calculate the `size` of `integerNode`?

This problem was then extended to `Node` class that contains a `Person` data like below:

```
class Node {
   Person data;
   Node left, right;
}
Node personNode = new Node(someHeavyPersonObject);
personNode.left=somePersonNode1;
personNode.right=somePersonNode2;
```

Assume that node is completely filled and `Person` object may be very heavy object.

***Does both `integerNode` and `personNode` have different sizes or same?***

These are the ***two ways I can think of***:

1. Node's size doesn't matter as it holds just the references and not the actual `data` object. So it would always occupy the size equivalent to three references(`data, left` and `right`).
2. Node's size depends upon the data object it holds.

I've looked into this question [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object) but it seems unrelated as I am looking for the logic for computing size (not actual size) without using any libraries like `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation`.

*Thanks in advance!!!*

Comment: What do you mean with size exactly? Number of bytes your code compiles to? Bytesize in terms of "one int is 4 byte, 2 ints are 8 byte" etc.?

Comment: @Ben By `size` I mean the one which it would occupy when its loaded in the main memory  /ram.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical interview question that is trying to determine if you fully understand how Java uses references and objects.

A good answer might be something like:

> The tree node itself would only take up as much space as the **references** it holds, in this case the space take by just **3** references. This allows Java objects to reside in different structures at the same time without taking more space.

Comment: Makes sense to me. But what if I generate 10000 random Integer objects at run time and create Nodes out of it? Wouldn't that be a part of node size?

Comment: @ShanuGupta - Yes and no - and it is this duality that someone with a clear understanding of Java would be able to explain. The tree itself would still use `3 * 10_000` space while the random numbers would take up another `10_000` making the total memory taken as `4 * 10_000`.